# Error creating directory on shared network

Tags: c#

Im having an exception (the handle is invalid) HR result -2147024890 when I create a directory in a shared network like this:

```
string path = @"\\server\path\to\folder";
if (Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
}
```

Do you know why and how to solve it?

Comment: do you get this error if you try to run this code on a directory not on a shared network (i.e. on your local machine)?

Comment: No, the problem only occurs when the path is a shared network.

Answer (score 0):

First the user account running the application must have access to the UNC path or this will not work. Simply do this:

```
const string PATH = @"<Your UNC Path>";

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(PATH);
            DirectorySecurity ds = di.GetAccessControl();
            Directory.CreateDirectory(PATH + @"\<Your new Dir>", ds);
```

Comment: I'm having an exception with this. HResult: -2147024809 Invalid handler. I have access to the unc and I can create directories.

Comment: Please confirm this is not an exception in you application vs with the sample code I submitted by adding the sample code to a simple console application. Make sure you are running the application by right clicking and selecting Run As Administrator to rule that out as well. For the running process confirm in task manager the actual user account that it is running under. Without knowing the context in which you are running the code its difficult to know where the error lies. Also ensure that targeted version of .net matches as well as the targeted architecture.